# Check if browser supports load method on iFrame

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, load

I'm trying to code a simple form with file upload which targets the iFrame. I've got it pretty much covered, but Internet Explorer does not support load method on dynamically generated iFrames so I need to do an alternative approach for it. My question is - what's the best and most accurate (plus light) way of identifying the browser type using Javascript?

I know that [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) can check for specific methods / properties, but not quite sure if it could help in this specific scenario. It has `Modernizr.hasEvent()`, but I can't use it to check the dynamically created elements.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're trying to detect whether your iframe supports the `onload` event, or something else? "load method" is a bit ambiguous :)

Comment: Sorry - it's the load event (onload in IE) - but with the dynamically generated iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check this, to my mind would be:

```
if ('onload' in iFrameVar)
{
    console.log('your code here');
}
```

Where iFrameVar is a reference to an iframe, of course:

```
function elemSupportsEvent(elem,e)
{
    var f = document.createElement(elem);
    if (e in f)
    {
        console.log(elem + ' supports the '+ e + ' event');
        return true;
    }
    console.log(elem + ' doesn\'t support the '+ e + ' event');
    return false;
}
elemSupportsEvent('iframe','onload');//logs "iframe supports the onload event" in chrome and IE8
```

Just a [quick fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPyKA/) by means of example of how you can use a function to check event support on various elements.

In response to your comment: if you want to check for dynamic content -as in ajax replies- you could simply use the `readystatechange` event:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        var parent = document.getElementById('targetContainerId');//suppose you're injecting the html here:
        parent.innerHTML += this.responseText;//append HTML
        onloadCallback.apply(parent,[this]);//call handler, with parent element as context, pass xhr object as argument
    }
};
function onloadCallback(xhr)
{
    //this === parent, so this.id === 'targetContainerId'
    //xhr.responseText === appended HTML, xhr.status === 200 etc...
    alert('additional content was loaded in the '+ this.tagName.toLowerCase+'#'+this.id);
   //alerts "additional content was loaded in the div/iframe/td/whatever#targetContainerID"
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by dynamically generated elements, if you mean `document.createElement` then yes, obviously (the code creates an empty node to check if the event is supported anyways), if you mean ajax content then, I suppose it does so, too - but in the latter scenario you have the `onreadystatechange` event, if the `readyState === 4` and `status === 200`, you could apply the `onready` event handler anyway, simply because you know the content has been loaded

Comment: What I meant by dynamic is the creation of the iframe on button click event. I tried the 'onready' event handler, but didn't seem to work. I've seen some comments elsewhere saying that IE needs onload="" attribute with the iframe in dynamically generated iframes in order to work, but I need to pass a number of parameters to the calling method therefore it's not an option for me.

Comment: But if you're creating it on-the-fly, in a hander, then just do something like `theIframe.apply(iframeLoadHandler,[some,args]);` just after the `parent.append(theIframe);` line... no need for an event listener, which is easier on your client anyhow (marginally, but lighter non the less). And if you've created the iFrame with `theIframe.onload = functionReference`, just doing `theIframe.onload();` allows you to fire the event manually anyway

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check support for particular event, you can try something like this :

```
var isEventSupported = (function(){
    var TAGNAMES = {
      'select':'input','change':'input',
      'submit':'form','reset':'form',
      'error':'img','load':'img','abort':'img'
    }
    function isEventSupported(eventName) {
      var el = document.createElement(TAGNAMES[eventName] || 'div');
      eventName = 'on' + eventName;
      var isSupported = (eventName in el);
      if (!isSupported) {
        el.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
        isSupported = typeof el[eventName] == 'function';
      }
      el = null;
      return isSupported;
    }
    return isEventSupported;
  })();
```

here is a live demo for the above :

http://kangax.github.com/iseventsupported/

Comment: Is this going to work with dynamically generated iframes in IE?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you didn't include the 'load':'iframe' in the TAGNAMES? Is that on purpose - will it work on the iframe without it?

Comment: @SpencerMark, you can change it iframe and test in ie, i dont have ie to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.userAgent`. It contains browser user agent

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE 6") == -1){
    // We've got IE.
}
```

Comment: Nasty! You should avoid detecting browsers and detect objects instead where possible! See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html

Comment: Say this to OP. I just answer on him question :)